# splay tree:What item is at the root

Tags: tree

> What item is at the root after the following sequence of insertions 
>   into an empty splay tree: 1, 11, 3, 10, 8, 4, 6, 5, 7, 9, 2?

Comment: the last entry will be the root, this is the main property of splay trees. See this post http://lowcoupling.com/post/81057347460/binary-search-avl-and-splay-trees

Answer (score 1):

```
This is How the Splay tree looks after inserting each element.
Each frame shows the splay tree after ith element is inserted.
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
I wish,it clears your doubt!!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the definition of a splay tree:

```
Splaying the tree for a certain element rearranges the tree so that the element is placed at the root of the tree.
```

So i believe it would always be the last element inserted.